# How would I know if I'm using PulseAudio, ALSA, or Jack?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

Ubuntu 20.04.1 (upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 -> 18.04 -> 20.04 if that matters)...

I have just done default install plus gnome-session-flashback and other non-audio related packages (Gimp, Blender, etc).  Aside from Yoshimi soft synthesizer, I have not intentionally played with or installed any additional audio [things], whatever PulseAudio, ALSA, Jack are.

How would I know if I'm using PulseAudio, ALSA, or Jack?  For example dmesg output mentions none of the three, where else do I check?

(needed to move along [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292805/how-to-eliminate-noticeable-midi-latency-even-with-linux-lowlatency) question along, as per a follow-up question in the comments)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if I'm using alsa or pulse-audio by default? (Switching to i3-wm)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426983/how-can-i-tell-if-im-using-alsa-or-pulse-audio-by-default-switching-to-i3-wm)

Comment: You could well be using all three - they can work together and their functions don't fully overlap.  For example, if you are using pulse then you are using it on top of alsa and you can use alsa directly if you wanted.  If you are using jack you are at minimum still providing pulse interfaces so things that use pulse keep working

Comment: ``alsa-info'' command

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to hear audio from things like the web browser (ie youtube), you are almost certainly running pulse. However, to be sure, try running

```
pactl list
```

on the terminal. If pulse isn't running, you'll get an error, or if it is running, it will give you a lot of information, which we can ignore for now.

For Jack, `qjackctl` is a very useful GUI app for controlling jack and doing audio and MIDI routing. When you start it, it will tell you if you're running jack or not.

It's possible to use jack and pulse at the same time, however, this is sometimes fiddly. What this means is that if you can hear web audio, this doesn't tell you whether or not you're running jack. However, it may be the case that when you start jack, all non-jack audio stops.

Depending on your audio app, you may need to tell it to use jack rather than pulse (or alsa).  For Yoshimi, this may be under the settings menu, which has tabs for Jack and ALSA.